# Error: pq: 1 columns must reference exactly 1 columns in referenced table (found 2)

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key, cockroachdb

I have a few tables and I am facing this issue most likely with the table "item". 
When I remove `restaurant_id` and `category_id`, it works fine.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS restaurant
(
    id              UUID NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
    title           VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS restaurant_gallery
(
    id              SERIAL,
    restaurant_id   UUID NOT NULL REFERENCES restaurant,
    image           VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, restaurant_id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS category
(
    id              SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    restaurant      UUID NOT NULL,
    label           VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,

    UNIQUE (restaurant, label)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS item
(
    id              SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    restaurant_id   UUID NOT NULL REFERENCES restaurant (id),
    category_id     SERIAL NOT NULL REFERENCES category (id),
    name            VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (id, restaurant_id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS item_gallery
(
    id              SERIAL,
    item_id         INT NOT NULL REFERENCES item,
    image           VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, item_id)
);
```

> Error:

```
pq: 1 columns must reference exactly 1 columns in referenced table (found 2)
Error: pq: 1 columns must reference exactly 1 columns in referenced table (found 2)
Failed running "sql"
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Why is `name` part of the primary key in `category`? That seems weird and is the cause of the error.

Comment: Makes sense. I actually wanted to INDEX these keys since I would query a lot with these...

Comment: That is too little information. Can you edit the question and adapt the table definitions to your changes? Otherwise I have no idea what you are doing. If you changed the primary key for `category` to `id`, the error message can no longer be `columns must reference exactly 1 columns in referenced table`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe The final change has worked for me. You can see in the edit. Changing PK() to UNIQUE()  for the item table... thank you...

Comment: There is still a syntax error (a comma after the last column definition of `restaurant`). Otherwise your code runs here.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe yeah, that happened as I am copy pasting from my editor...

Comment: Please do not change the question. You can revert to its first revision and post the good code that works **as an answer**.

Answer (score 1):

For a foreign key, you need to tell Postgres which *table* you want to refer to *and* the name(s) of the *field(s)* within that table that you want to use as the foreign key(s):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS item
(
    id              SERIAL,
    restaurant_id   UUID         NOT NULL  REFERENCES restaurant ( id ) 
    category_id     INT          NOT NULL  REFERENCES category ( id ) 
    name            VARCHAR(25)  NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, restaurant_id)
);
```

Comment: This is giving me `pq: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table category
Error: pq: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table category
Failed running "sql"
`

Comment: Perhaps because your category table has no Primary Key ("unique constraint") for the Foreign Key to refer to?

Comment: Added it, and I'm back to the original problem...

Comment: Your item_gallery table is attempting to reference your item table but this has a Primary key on "(id, restaurant_id)".  You need to include both of these in the Foreign Key from item-gallery.

Comment: The problem has been solved. Check the comment section.

Comment: @PhillW. you don't have to state the columns in an FK reference. If you state only the table, then it is assumed that you want to reference the PK (of that table).

Comment: @ypercube: Accepted when the Primary Key is only a single column but this appears to be a Composite Key and so would require an explicit Foreign Key clause listing all the fields.

Comment: No, you don't need it, doesn't matter how many columns the PK has: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=9b2dcff923ed2aed1d6932d830788215 But anyway, this is not the issue with the question here/ As you have written in your comment, the problem is the mismatch of the FK and the referenced PK (1 vs 2 columns).